# How to apply claims-based authentication to a .NET 4 application?

Tags: security, authentication, single-sign-on, claims-based-identity

AFAIK, .NET 4.5+ support claims-based authentication but not the lower versions, e.g. .NET 4 apps. Is there any way to apply claims-based authentication to my applications (as Relying Parties) without upgrading them to .NET 4.5 to have the benefits of SSO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before .NET 4.5 - WIF (Windows Identity Foundation) was used as an add-on library to add claims, ws-federation etc. It is on the wire compatible with .NET 4.5.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17331

Comment: Thank you Dom! I will google more for the detailed implementation. By the way, I really appreciate your contribution to the community regarding claims-based identity. Your book and courses on Pluralsight are super helpful. Again, thank you!